# Alexa skill - how to invoke Alexa intent skill with a number

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Newbie -- trying to figure out how to implement in Alexa skill that just jumps right in. Eg. say, a pizza finder skill:

e.g.

```
User: "Alexa run Pizza Finder"
Alexa:  "OK, what's your zip code?"
User: 98132 
Alexa:  Thanks.  If you want me to find the closest pizza store, tell me your address.  Otherwise, I can give you ad list.  Just say "give me a list".
```

So right now I have the launchIntent say "OK what's your zip code".

But I can't figure out how to launch the "findPizzaStoreIntent" just by having somebody say a "98132".

Comment: A couple approaches utilize the device address api call : https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/device-address-api.html and pull your pizza store address api call from that, or create a get zip code intent and store it as a session attribute then go to the find pizza intent and use an api call to yelp or whoever you’ll pull the localized info from. Hope that’s helpful.

Comment: Also what you described in your question is a launch, then a question (zip code intent) a reply a question  which will require a response either address or list(pizza finder intent) and the users reply will be worked out by you on the returned list or localized address logic.